# Why does an unawaited Future error make my test fail?

Tags: dart, testing, async-await

Given this minimal test

```dart
      test('ignore failures', () {
        Future<void> failingFunc() async {
          throw Exception('BOOOOM');
        }

        failingFunc();
      });
```

The test fails with this output :

```
Exception: BOOOOM
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>.failingFunc
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:374
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:377
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                                 _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
test/unit/features/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart         main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>.failingFunc
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:1
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:377
```

**In don't understand why that test fails.**

My understanding is that `failingFunc()` would fail “silently” because it’s not *awaited*.  (i.e. the exception would be thrown “somewhere else”, and just ignored)
I’m (almost) certain that such a thing in production code would work just fine.

The following test does fail the way I expect it to  (i.e. adding an `await` ) :

```dart
      test('ignore failures', () async {
        Future<void> failingFunc() async {
          throw Exception('BOOOOM');
        }

        await failingFunc();
      });
```

and it fails as expected with

```
Exception: BOOOOM
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>.failingFunc
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:374
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
test/…/auth/auth_action_bloc_test.dart:377
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception will be thrown somewhere else, but it will most certainly not be ignored.

An uncaught asynchronous error, which this is, is reported to the current `Zone`'s uncaught error handler. If you do nothing special, that's the root zone, which will terminate the program on an uncaught error.

Well, it will do so in native code. On the web, you can't crash the browser, so it will just be treated as an unhandled JavaScript error, which may or may not be ignored. It's still bad style, and makes debugging harder, so you shouldn't let errors be unhandled in production.

The `test` package runs each test in a new zone with an uncaught-error handler, so it knows which test caused the exception. It also recognizes that the error happened *after* it had already considered that test done and successful. If you're lucky, it will go back and mark the test as failing from throwing that error, even if it does so much later. If unlucky, and slow, and all tests are done and the test runner has printed the results, then it might be too late to go back and change the result.

Example:

```dart
import "package:test/test.dart";

void main() {
  test("example", () {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => throw "error");
  });
  test("delayed", () => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)));
}
```

In this example, the `test` package recognizes that the `"example"` test fails, even if it does so after it has returned and pretended all is well.
If you change the duration of `"delayed"` to zero, then it reports that both tests are successful, before the first tests uncaught error happens, and it just prints `00:00 +2: All tests passed!`.

If you actually *want* to ignore errors from a future, you have to do something.
Since Dart 2.14, you can write:

```dart
 failingFunc().ignore();
```

The `ignore()` is an extension method on `Future` declared in `dart:async`/`dart:core` which catches and ignores errors from the future
it's called on.
Use with care, errors might be significant.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Then with your example, this means that possibly running a single test of the file, or running them all possibly wouldn't give the same outcome ?

Comment: Yes. A single test should be complete when it returns, or, if it returns a future, when that future completes. Nothing should happen after that inside the test (for several reasons, one being that _`tearDown` has been called_, and potentially `setUp` for one or more other tests has been run since. Shared variables are very much clobbered).  
So, handling a completed test throwing after that point, or doing anything at all, is very much "best effort" with no guaranteed result, and it's something you should try to avoid. Don't leave dangling future's.